# Show a(n) <li> formated as a flexbox based on @media query

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

I am having trouble displaying and hiding some `<li>` items based on a media query. I have a `<ul>` element which is displayed as flexbox, containing `<li>` elements. Each respective `<li>` is also displayed as flexbox, containing an icon and text. I want two `<li>` elements (the first one and the last one) to show when the screen width is 925px or less. However, this only seems to work when the `<li>` elements are NOT displayed as flexboxes. However, I need the `<li>` elements to be flexboxes, so I can format the icon and text simply. Is there any way I can show / hide `<li>` elements based on the screen width if the `<li>` elements are formated as flexboxes?

I have the code in the link below, which is the same as the code shown below in this post.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYrxmG

The `<li>` elements that I want to show when the screen width is less than 925px is denoted by a pink background.

```
     <nav id="navigation">
            <ul id="nav-content">
                <li id="nav-left"></li>
                <li id="op1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x30"><h2>Option1</h2></li>
                <li id="op2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x30"><h2>Option2</h2></li>
                <li id="op3"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x30"><h2>Option3</h2></li>
                <li id="op4"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x30"><h2>Option4</h2></li>
                <li id="nav-right"></li>
              </ul>
        </nav>

    * {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      color: black;
    }

    #nav-content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      list-style-type: none;
      border: solid 2px black;
    }

    // Each list element in nav bar
    #nav-content>li {
      // When this display: flex is turned on, my <li> gets formatted correctly
      // but the pink elements stop showing based on media query
      //display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    }

    #nav-content > li:hover {
      background-color: grey;
    }

    #nav-left, #nav-right {
      display: none;
      background-color: pink;
    }

    @media (max-width: 500px) {
      #nav-left,
      #nav-right {
        display: flex;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to only be a matter of selector's weight :

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: black;
}

#nav-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

#nav-content > li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}

#nav-content > li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

#nav-content > #nav-left,
#nav-content > #nav-right {
  display: none;
  background-color: pink;
}

@media (max-width: 925px) {
  #nav-content > #nav-left,
  #nav-content > #nav-right {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
      <ul id="nav-content">
        <li id="nav-left"></li>
        <li id="op1"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30"><h2>Option1</h2></li>
        <li id="op2"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30"><h2>Option2</h2></li>
        <li id="op3"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30"><h2>Option3</h2></li>
        <li id="op4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30"><h2>Option4</h2></li>
        <li id="nav-right"></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

fix & [forked pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKbQWJ):

```
#nav-content > #nav-left,
#nav-content > #nav-right {
  display: none;
  background-color: pink;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #nav-content > #nav-left,
  #nav-content > #nav-right {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```